# page-router-outlet navigate using Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, router

I have a problem in my routing.ts code. So, I tried this code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
      { path: 'fp', component: FirstPageComponent },
      { path: 'events', component: EventsComponent },
      { path: 'package', component: PackageComponent },
      { path: 'package/:id', component: PackageGetByIdComponent },
      { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
      { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginFirstComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'usersforgetpassword', component: ResetPassComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I want to navigate in FirstPageComponent, not in HomeComponent. My HomeComponent have this code:

```
 <menu-app></menu-app> 
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
<menu_bar-app></menu_bar-app>
```

And I can't put data in this component because those data show in all components.

When I login in app, my login function navigate in /home/fp
When I stay login, my app open /home

I want to navigate in /home/fp when I stay login.

HomeComponent have:

```
<menu-app></menu-app> 
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
<menu_bar-app></menu_bar-app>
```

FirstPageComponent have:

```
<ActionBar title="Home" backgroundColor="#EE6E73" color="#FFFFFF">
    <ActionItem android.position="true" [nsRouterLink]="['/home/profile']">
        <img src="~/assets/images/male.png" width="30" height="30" stretch="aspectFit" padding='15' />
    </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
    <GridLayout rows="*,60">
            <ScrollView backgroundColor="#f1f1f1">

                <StackLayout>
                 <label text="First Page"></label>
                </StackLayout>
             </ScrollView>
    </GridLayout>
```

AuthGuard:

```
canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
}
```

Can you ask me any idea please?

Comment: I don't see your issue clearly. Can you put it better? Or some stackblitz reproducing your issue.

Comment: first, dont use `page-router-outlet` in any files except `app.component.html` (or the template in app.component.ts if you use templates). second, you cant navigate to a sibling inside of a sibling, you need to do navigate to it from the top level

Comment: @AmitChigadani the issue is that the OP wants to navigate to a sibling when they cant, only the children of `home`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon But `FirstPageComponent` is a child of `HomeComponent`, not a sibling component.

Comment: @AmitChigadani my bad, i read `FirstPageComponent` as `LoginFirstComponent`, but my first point stands and is probably the reason why

Comment: No, `router-outlet` is always required inside the parent component to load their children. If not added, child components will not get loaded.

Comment: yes, `router-outlet` are required in parents except the top level (app.component) but the OP has used a `page-router-outlet` in his `home` component which is wrong

Comment: `router-outlet` in `home` component is still valid because its a parent component, or else it cannot load child components.

Comment: it is valid but the OP uses `page-router-outlet`, not `router-outlet`

Comment: Please, I'm very confused, can you write something, how to navigate from top level? Thnx

Comment: can you please add the code which you use to try and navigate from `home` to `fp`

Comment: I edit my post. Thnx